# What does a blue filename in Windows Explorer mean?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filenames

I am viewing a network share where some filenames are in blue instead of black. I am using Windows 7.

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/66121/cant-copy-file-with-green-filename-access-denied) mentions green filenames, which indicates encrypted file.

What does a blue filename indicate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is blue because that means it is compressed with [NTFS compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#File_compression).

As a note, although I am not sure why anyone would do this, this can be turned off by opening Computer, holding down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, and going to Tools>Folder Options>View and unchecking "Show encrypted or compressed NTFS files in color".

Comment: Not usually, always.  Blue entries in Explorer indicate that the NTFS compression attribute is set on the file or folder.

Comment: @afrazier That "always" was someone else's edit. I agree with you and will re-edit it.

Comment: I don't know why Windows 10 turns off this feature by default unlike previous versions. I always have to turn it on manually